# Processing two text files into a python matrix

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, exception, matrix

A chocolate company has decided to offer discount on the candy products which are produced 30 days of more before the current date. I have to have a matrix as a print result where the program reads through 2 files, one being the the cost of the different candies of different sizes, and another being the threshold number of days after which the discount is offered. So in this question the two text files look something like this

candies.txt

```
31 32 19 11 15 30 35 37
12 34 39 45 66 78 12 7
76 32 8 2 3 5 18 32 48
99 102 3 46 88 22 25 21
fd zz er 23 44 56 77 99 
44 33 22 55 er ee df 22
```

and the second file days.txt

```
Discount at days = 30
```

It should print

```
      $  $  $         
$                $  $ 
      $ $ $ $  $      
       $       $  $  $ 
?  ?  ? $       
      $     ?  ?  ?   $
```

So basically, everywhere the number is under 30(which is the input from days.txt) it should print a `"$"` sign and everywhere it is more than the number(30 in our case) it should just print spaces in their place. We also have an anomally, where we have the english alphabets in the candies.txt matrix and since we are looking for numbers to check the price and not letters, it should print a `"?"` sign in their place as it is not recognized.

Here is what I am trying to do.

```
def candyShop(candy, price):
    try:
        candyfile = open("candes.txt", "r")
        readCategory = process_file(candyfile)
        if readCategory str.isdigit():
            if readCategory > 30:
                print("$")
        elif:
            print("?")
        else:
            print("")

    return candyShop()
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I am trying to attempt writing a code for the description above. Just need some help/hints.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. If you have a specific question about a problem you've run into, preferably with code that shows you've already done some effort and research, we'd be happy to help

Comment: I would really appreciate if Stack Overflow members should mind their own business instead of trolling questions they do not want to help with. If you feel like helping someone, great! otherwise, why bother? Can I just wait here and if someone feels helpful, they will lend me a hand.

Comment: You're not asking for somebody to lend you a hand, you're asking for somebody to do the work for you. This is a site where programmers, both professionals and beginners, can get help with specific problems, not where you can get answers to "that really hard problem my mean old professor assigned me"

Comment: I would much rather not talk to someone who is trying to bully people online. You do not own Stack Overflow and hence cannot speak for it. Bye.

Comment: what is `process_file` here? Do you have a function named `process_file`?

Comment: @PaulJacobsen: Don't be such a hypocrite, it's quite obvious this is part of a homework. Even your "tried" code has many syntax and logic errors, just exactly like a teacher would give you in order for you to fix. It is obvious you didn't even try your code, or else you'd notice that you have a partial "try" clause, and the expression in the isdigit() check is completely wrong. This is definitely a "do it for me plz" post, which is really frowned in S.O, specially when the OP doesn't even try to get a proper solution by himself, just like you did. IMO you are the troll here. Bye.

Answer (score 0):

You should understand that we have to process the file and reshape the data in way that you can use the data later. What about a 2D list?

```
parsedList=[]
with open("demo.txt","r") as f:
    lst=f.read().splitlines()
    for i in lst:
        parsedList.append(i.split())
```

Well, the data is stored well. Now task is simple, traverse each item, check the element according to your condition and print them off accordingly.

```
with open("days.txt","r") as f:
    param = int(f.readline().split("=")[1])

for innerList in parsedList:
    for element in innerList:
        if element.isdigit():
            if int(element)>=param:
                print " ",
            else:
                print "$",
        else:
            print "?",
    print
```

Comment: So how would we use the second text file? the number 30 actually comes from the second text file and it can be anything. It can even change, so we cannot hard code it.

Comment: Thank you! It is taking the values from the files but not printing in a matrix form...

Answer (score 0):

The [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html)-aware way.

Note that the `join()` saves testing for last iterations (horrible) or stripping trailing blanks. (ugly)

Of course you have to load data from file instead of using a ready-made string `DATA` , but that shouldn't be too great a task.

To get `threshold` parsed out of a config file, you can also use `re`or plain string `split()` function.

```
import re

DATA = '''
31 32 19 11 15 30 35 37
12 34 39 45 66 78 12 7
76 32 8 2 3 5 18 32 48
99 102 3 46 88 22 25 21
fd zz er 23 44 56 77 99 
44 33 22 55 er ee df 22
'''

PLACEHOLDER = ' '
DISCOUNT_MARKER = '$'
VOID_MARKER = '?'

SEP = PLACEHOLDER # your mileage may vary


def dump(x, threshold):
    s = None
    try: 
        if int(x) < threshold:
            s = DISCOUNT_MARKER
        else:     
            s = PLACEHOLDER
    except ValueError:
        s = VOID_MARKER 
    return s


if __name__ == '__main__':
    threshold = 30 # gather that from the config file

    for line in DATA.splitlines()[1:]:
        print(SEP.join(
            map(lambda x: dump(x.group(0), threshold), 
                re.finditer('(\w+)', line)
            )
        ))
```

output:

```
     $ $ $      
$           $ $
    $ $ $ $ $    
    $     $ $ $
? ? ? $        
    $   ? ? ? $
```

Comment: This is really good, but we cannot hard-code the data. It has to read from both the text files. The first text file has the matrix data and the second one has the value for which we need to convert the characters into a $, space or a ?. The value in the second file can change

Comment: I'm aware of that, please read the introductory text. My job was to show a idomatic way to do that matrix mapping; yours is now to adopt that algorithm for your external files.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am trying to write the code but still don't quite get it. Could you please help me with parsing the files?

Comment: @PaulJacobsen Well, first try and guess how a function that **read**s **lines** from the opened data file is called, and how a function that **split**s the config string read from the config file into a list of 3 words is called.